# Payment Method installed but doesnt show up

Tags: magento

I'm making a custom Payment Method for `Magento`.
It shows up in the disable modules output list (under configuration->advanced), but I can't see it anywhere in the payment methods.
Any clues on where I might have gone wrong.I know this is a little vague.I'd be happy to provide more info about relevant things.

Comment: Did you logout and then back in? Sometimes this is a pre-requisite after installing new modules. If it's not in the Payment methods section, check to see if it has it's own menu section on the configuration menu.

Comment: Logged out and flushed the cache as well.this is a recent problem..i installed the same thing on my windows system and it showed up. i am presently working on a linux system.

Answer (score 1):

If, like the commentators said, you cleaned  and still have this problem, then It seems that your module is present in etc/modules but for some reason :

-The path assigned in etc/modules doesn´t match in your code folder (where there is core, local, and community folder)

-The path is found, but your config file  doesn't have the  tags correctly configured. 
     In this case look:

[Magento custom payment module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/payment/create-payment-method-module)

And search for the tags that i mentioned.

Off course, you have to set your system.xml too, it is described in the same link.

Comment: So it turns out that my config file wasnt properly made.Thanks a tonne for the help!

Comment: Sorry but i'm facing the same problem yet again.Checked all the abover things but the plugin doesnt show up. Has this got to do with setting up plugin on windows/linux?